# Pass data to component after it has finished routing

Tags: authentication, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have a navbar-login (login form in navbar) and a page-login (a page with login-form which can be routed to). The navbar-login-form and the page-login-form are two-way-binded via a service (see first codebit below).

What I want is the following flow:

1. User enters email and password in navbar-login
2. On Clicking Submit Button, the credentials are sent to a login.service
3. If credentials are wrong, the service routes to the login-page with the credentials displayed

**The two-way-binding with the service works fine if the page-login is already displayed. But if it wasn't displayed and I enter credentials and hit the button, it only routes to page-login but does not pass the credentials.**

I'm using the following service to have navbar-login and page-login communicate with each other (two-way-binding across "unrelated" components):

```ts
export class LoginNav2PageService {

    viewerChange: EventEmitter<{email:string,password:string}> = new EventEmitter();
    constructor() {}
    emitNavChangeEvent(user:{email:string,password:string}) {
        this.viewerChange.emit(user);
    }
    getNavChangeEmitter() {
        return this.viewerChange;
    }
}
```

This is the navbar component, pass2page is hooked with a keyup event in the HTML inputs:

```ts
export class LoginNavbarComponent {
    user:= {email:'',password:''};

    constructor(private _loginNav2pageService:LoginNav2PageService, private _loginService:LoginService){}

    pass2page(){
        this._loginNav2pageService.emitNavChangeEvent(this.user);
    }

  onNavbarLoginBtn(){
    this._loginService.onNavbarLogin(this.user);
  }
}
```

And this is the listener in the page-login component:

```ts
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit{
    user= {email:"", password:""};
    subscription:any;

    constructor(private _loginNav2pageService:LoginNav2PageService){}

    ngOnInit():any{
        this.subscription = this._loginNav2pageService.getNavChangeEmitter().subscribe(user => this.setViewer(user));
    }

    setViewer(user:{email:string, password:string}){
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And finally the loginService:

```ts
export class LoginService{
  constructor(private _router:Router, private _loginNav2pageService:LoginNav2PageService){}
  //login User from Navbar
  onNavbarLogin(user:LoginUserInterface){
    //login and routing if successful
    if(user.email === 'name' && user.password === '1234'){
      console.log("Login Success");
      //route to platform
    }
    //else route to login page to show validation errors to users
    else {
      this._router.navigate(['Login']);
      this._loginNav2pageService.emitNavChangeEvent(user);
      console.log("wrong credentials");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have done too much work

Comment: Only single shared service can do what you want. Its even quite tough to figure out what you are trying to achieve with given data. you needed to use single shared service with shared object.

Comment: yeah...after a good nights sleep I figured it out :), the code above was a snippet i adapted before in some other parts.... Now i'm simply using the ngAfterViewInit Lifecycle Hook to get the data from the service. Thanks!

Comment: That's great but still this can be optimized as I said. best of luck !

Answer (score 0):

after a good nights sleep I figured it out :), the code above was a snippet i adapted before in some other parts and way to complicated for this....

Now i'm simply using the ngAfterViewInit Lifecycle Hook to get the data from the service.

Thanks!